# Prove that $f(f(x)) - f(x) = x +1$, is one to one

Tags: functions

Given:
 $Df = \mathbb{R}$

And, $f(f(x)) - f(x) = x + 1$

Prove that $f$ is inverse. I've busted my head with this one. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Welcome! I have edited your answer the proper formatting. Please double check that it's indeed what you meant. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Let $f(x)=f(y)$. Then $x+1 = f(f(x)) - f(x) = f(f(y))-f(y) = y+1$ and so $x=y$.

Comment: Oh god that was so simple. I feel pretty stupid to be honest. Thanks for the quick answers anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=f(y)$. Apply $f$ on both sides to get $f(f(x))=f(f(y))$. So $f(x)+x+1=f(y)+y+1$. Since $f(x)=f(y)$ we get $x=y$.

Answer (score -1):

**Restriction:** Here we assume that we are looking for functions nice enough to have power series expansions of some radius of convergence around every point.

Then we rewrite $$f(x) = 1+x+f(f(x))$$

Now it is trivial to see that $f(f(x))$ will expand into a higher order polynomial for any truncation to an order >1 we can make. So $f(x)$ must be the equation of a line:

$$f(x) = a+bx$$

A linear function is inversible.

( With risk of sounding arrogant, from an engineering perspective all interesting smooth-enough functions are like this anyways. )

Comment: I don't think $f$ is linear. If $f$ is linear, then $f(0)=0$. However, $1+0+f(f(0))=1$. Hence the equality does not hold in $0$. Am I missing something?

Comment: @InsideOut I mean first order polynomial. A straight line with offset.

Comment: I see what you mean. Personally speaking, I would say affine in this case just to avoid confusion.

Comment: It should be clear from context of truncated power series that truncation at order 1 is what is meant. But yes it is always good to be extra careful with wording, I suppose.